# What is the best way to transform an object with nested resources in another service in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest

Let's assume that we have two micro-services, one responsible for schools and the other for students. We need to build an endpoint in students which will list students associated with their school information. Response Example:

```
  {
    students: [
      {
        name: "Mark",
        age: 13,
        school: {
          name: "International School",
          address: "...",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm not that experienced in laravel, but from what I can see in the current code written, that in the transformer itself, there's an API call which will fetch the school information for each student. Which is causing N+1 API request problem.

So, need you help in knowing what is the cleanest way to avoid this issue?

Comment: you could utilize joins via query builder or establish relationships through eloquent so that you avoid n+1 queries

Comment: Could you share the schema in the post?

Comment: Thanks @Kevin for you answer, I believe my question is not clear. I mean the data is into separate micro-services. So, will need to do an api request for that

Comment: @Aashishgaba Each student has id of his school associated to it. Please tell me if you need more details about the schema.

Comment: You mean, student table has school_id as its column, meaning one to many (School <=> Student) relationship ?

Comment: yes exactly....

Answer (score 0):

Student Model

```
public function school(){
   return $this->belongsTo(App\School::class, 'school_id', 'id');
}
```

School Model

```
public function students(){
    return $this->hasMany(App\Student::class, 'school_id', 'id');
}
```

Controller

```
$students = Student::with('school')->get();
```

This eager loads your relationship meaning number of queries are reduced to 2 from N + 1 in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Aashish but the two models actually are not in the same code base. They are two different micro-services. You may assume that I need to call a third party API to get the school information.

Comment: Do they share a common database?. I mean they have to right, otherwise how do you assign a school_id to a student? Explain me the structure, I could help you in a better way if I know how it works and what is needed ? :)

Comment: No database is not shared. When a student is assigned to a school, we just validate the school id from the school service.

Comment: Okay, so here's what you can do to reduce the number of queries. Make a get API first in your student service to get all the schools. I'm sure you would be already doing that to let student get assigned to a school. So once you have all the schools. Iterate over them, create a map where school_id is mapped to school information. Now when you try to list the students, get the school id from the student, use the map to get the school information. There you go. You just had to make one API call to get all the schools and rest of it was taken care by map. It would reduce the time by huge factor.